# Thymeleaf generates an error when accessing any route

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In a spring boot(2.2.6) api I'm returning my frontend(vuejs) from the static folder:

```
src
  main 
    resources
      static
        site
          index.html
          css 
          js
      templates
        master.html
        pdf.html
```

---

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class UiController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/admin/**")
    public ModelAndView index(Model model, Principal principal) {
        UserDetail userDetail = (UserDetail) ((Authentication) principal).getPrincipal();

        model.addAttribute("index", "../static/site/index.html");
        return new ModelAndView("master");
    }

}
```

I am also generating a PDF with thymeleaf and itextpdf.

```
.
.
.
String orderHtml = templateEngine.process("pdf", context);

ByteArrayOutputStream target = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
converterProperties.setBaseUri("http://localhost:9000"); 

HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(orderHtml, target, converterProperties);
.
.
.
```

By accessing the frontend api path in the url: http://localhost:9000/admin
the frontend is not displayed.
Generating this error:

```
rg.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: 
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: 
Error resolving template [error], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

But I can call the route that generates the pdf perfectly.
Can I be forgetting something?

Comment: wrong mapping url convert it to `/admin`

Comment: did not solve..